# R plot line directly as raster array without saving to file

Tags: r, plot, raster

I have been looking around for how to plot directly as raster array, rather than have to plot to a file and then load it back. See the code below

```
iter=1;
thumbnail_list=list();
tr=apply(datamatrix,1,function(x){
        png(sprintf("./tmpplot/p_%s.png",iter), height=40,width=80)    #plot to a png file
        par(mar=c(0,0,0,0));
        plot(x,type="l",xlab="",ylab="")
        dev.off()
        thumbnail_list[[iter]]<<-readPNG(sprintf("./tmpplot/p_%s.png",iter)).  #load it back to memory
        iter<<-iter+1
})
```

datamatrix contains 100 rows, each row 50 columns (i.e. each row is a line with 50 points).
I think my current strategy is tedious and there should be better way.

Basically I want to generate an image labeled plot like this 
[image]
Currently I have to "plot each of those small image to file" separately and the load back through readPNG, and add to plot with rasterimage.

How to avoid the "plot to file" step?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(datamatrix)
plot(r)
image(r)
```

And more advanced plotting in other packages

Comment: No. I need a magic version of "plot" that does not plot to file(or screen), but returns something like that returned by readPNG